Triggering a small black powder charge with an STM32
I am trying to design a flight controller system that can trigger some small low-power explosive charges as described here. The description states that the charges will ignite with as little as 2V at 0.2 amps. I would like to trigger these charges with an STM32 microcontroller but I am not sure how I would do so.
I am thinking I will use a MOSFET connected to my 9V power source, but I am not sure what specific properties I am looking for to find the right MOSFET model to use for this application. I was also considering using a relay instead of a MOSFET.

Apparently, the PDF shows a preexisting board for this purpose. Do you have available a name, model, and datasheet for that board? Also, this isn't rocket science --- oh, I'm wrong, it is ;) --  so it's not going to be difficult. Regardless of whatever circuit you land on, it should be very easy to test it out and make sure it is robust and does the job. Personally, I'd want to ensure a guaranteed all-fire in less than 250 ms. Shorter still would be better in my mind. Keep a logbook on your experiments. Use a fast video recording setting and make movies to review.

I don't know what your power source is, but on a per weight basis, you may get more current from a small  3.8 v Li-ion cell than from a common 9 v battery.

I feel like you could use a spark ignitor like what you see for pilot lights in water boilers and fireplaces.

@MathKeepsMeBusy, I made a small mistake, the current required is 0.2 amps, not 0.5.

@Colin I am intending to use this for a rocket, I believe those reusable spark ignitors would be too heavy compared to a wire

@Jark If your 9 V power source is an ordinary 9 V battery, I doubt it can supply enough power to ignite anything less sensitive than nitrogen triiodide.

@Hearth If you look at the pdf, the design uses the filament of small christmas lights to ignite the charge. I doubt that those tiny lights require a lot of current.

There are things about your question that make me concerned such as the following list of words: flight, explosive charge, trigger and 9 volt power source (aka a battery). Your question therefore concerns me greatly.

@Andy aka I can assure you that you can put your worries to rest, this is all normal rocketry... however, if another incident with a passenger airliner occurs... maybe it wasn't just boeing.

I'll keep my eye on the TV news channel lol
